How do i make a type where an object is in it if it passes a condition?
It's would be cool if an object is in a type if the object passes a certain condition like
type x = object has a key "x" ? it is in : never

or maybe:
type x = object.k == object.w ? it is in : never

or actually:
type x = ComplicatedFunction(object) ? it is in : never

But unfortunately, type definitions dont allow value parameters, so there must be some convoluted way to make this happen. If it isn't possible, tell me why you think so, Thanks!

Do you mean { x: unknown }? That will match all objects with an x property. Eg, { x: 'foo' }, and { x: 2 }, but not { bar: 'baz' }. If that's not what you mean, could you give some examples of what the expected behavior is?

@NicholasTower That is exactly what i mean

@NicholasTower but let me edit to have many condition examples rq.

The type { x: unknown } will match all objects that have an x property, regardless of what value that x contains.
type X = { x: unknown };

const a: X = { x: 'foo' }
const b: X = { x: 2 }
const c: X = { x: undefined } // Explicit undefined is ok
const d: X = { } // Error
const e: X = { bar: 'baz' } // Error

Playground link

this works for the if object has key "x", Thanks!

Try this code:
type HasKeyX<T> = 'x' extends keyof T ? T : never;

// Example usage:
type Obj1 = HasKeyX<{ x: string; y: number }>;  // Should be { x: string; y: number }
type Obj2 = HasKeyX<{ y: number }>;            // Should be never

// To demonstrate, we'll create functions that return types
function testObj1(): Obj1 {
  return { x: 'hello', y: 10 };
}

function testObj2(): Obj2 {
  // @ts-expect-error This should raise a TypeScript error because Obj2 is 'never'
  return { y: 20 };
}

console.log('Obj1 function returns:', testObj1());
// The next line should not compile if uncommented, demonstrating type enforcement
// console.log('Obj2 function returns:', testObj2());


that was the simple condition

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
